# Column position visual selection line by line

Tags: vim, position, selection, block

**example**:

```
text téxt text |text| text
text text text |text| text
text téxt téxt |text| text
text téxt text |text| téxt
```

I'm selecting a block of text '|text|' of above lines

What I want to know is the column position of the startcolumn and endcolumn of every single line.

If I use:

```
echo col('"<') --> 17  
echo col('">') --> 20
```

it gives me the startcolumn of the 1st line of the block and the endcolumn of the last line of the block.

However there are multibytes characters before my block selection in every line. I want to know col('"<') and col('">') of every single line:

17, 20
16, 19
18, 21
17, 20

How can I obtain these?

Comment: Please give more background; what is your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Not easy in a few phrases what I want to do with it. I want to create a list or dictionary with the start and end columns of my visual selection. Then in a python script I change the matches and put them back in the text (using string manipulation) The problem is that Python uses unicode match positions and vim byte index so when there are multi byte chars in the text everything goes wrong. Hope I made myself clear. (It's a bit complicated to describe what I do with the matches but I think it's not necessary to describe my question)

Comment: If there's a mismatch between Python and Vim indexing, I would rather return a list of strings from Python and do the replacement in Vim (with `setline()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start with the begin and end columns of the visual (blockwise) selection. These are *screen columns*, i.e. counting screen cells. You want to translate them into byte indexes, for each covered line.

So, we need a way to translate screen columns into byte indexes. If we use the cursor, there are convenient functions to position it on a particular screen column (the `[N]|` command), and functions to query the byte index (`col()`). So, the overall algorithm transforms the screen columns of the start and end of the selection (marks `'<` and `'>`, respectively), obtained via `virtcol()`, into the byte index by positioning the cursor.

Here's one way to implement this:

```
:'<,'>global/^/
\   let positions = [] |
\   for mark in ['<', '>'] |
\       exe 'normal!' virtcol("'" . mark) . '|' |
\       call add(positions, col('.')) |
\   endfor |
\   echo positions
[17, 20]
[16, 19]
[18, 21]
[17, 20]
```

The start and end *screen* columns of the selection can be obtained through `virtcol()`. We can then position the cursor on the start and then the end position, and obtain the byte index via `col('.')`.

For simplicity, I here used `:global` to iterate over all selected lines, and put the columns into a list.

Comment: You're a genius! :) I'm trying to put the code in my vimscript but I can't make it work without the '|" 's and "\" 's.   - I still do not totally understand what you're doing. Can I use it also to know the col('.') values of a visual selection (not a block)? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As `virtcol({mark})` returns the character indexes, you can use it as counter in regexes.

For instance, we have:

```
let first_col = virtcol("'<")
let last_col = virtcol("'>")
```

From here, the 3 parts on each line can be obtained with

```
let lead      = matchstr(getline(n), '\v^.{'.(first_col-1).'}')
let selection = matchstr(getline(n), '\v^.{'.(first_col-1).'}\zs.{'.(last_col-first_col+1).'}')
let tail      = matchstr(getline(n), '\v^.{'.(last_col).'}\zs.*')
```

Or we can also use `matchlist()`

```
let [all, lead, selection, tail; dummy] = matchlist(getline('.'), '\v^(.{'.(first_col-1).'})(.{'.(last_col-first_col+1).'})(.*)')
```

I guess we should be able to use `split()` also, but it would be convoluted.

Note that thanks to this manual counting, we have a regex, and thus we would be able to use `:'<,'>substitute` directly. In that case, it would be even more simple to directly use [`\%V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25V) in the pattern. But beware, it's a little bit tricky to use correctly: to signal the end of the match, we need to negate the pattern. See this [discussion on vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13212/626) for a little bit more explanations on the subject.

```
:'<,'>s/\v^(.{-})%V(.{-})%V@!(.*)/\1##\2##\3/
```

Or if you prefer to apply functions on each match, the `\1##\2##\3` could become: `\=(func1(submatch(1)).func2(submatch(2)).func3(submatch(3))`. This way, you could reserve the python part to the implementation of the various `funcn()`  functions. Note that you could pass several parameters to these functions if you want, or even to call a single function with the individual matches: `\=singlefunc(submatch(1), submatch(2), submatch(3))`